# printing 2d array as string trouble - java

Tags: java

Im trying to print this 2d array

```
public class TicTacToe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[][] gameBoard = {
                {' ' + '|' + ' ' + '|' + ' '},
                {'-' + '+' + ' ' + '+' + '-'},
                {' ' + '|' + ' ' + '|' + ' '},
                {'-' + '+' + ' ' + '+' + '-'},
                {' ' + '|' + ' ' + '|' + ' '}
        };
        for(char[] row : gameBoard){
            for(char symbol : row){
                System.out.print(symbol);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
     }
   }
```

however my output is just

Ř
Ð
Ř
Ð
Ř

What am i doing wrong? I used a youtube video to help and they did practically the same thing and it worked fine for them.

Comment: How would you initialize an int array? Would you write `new int[]{1 + 2 + 3}` or `new int[]{1, 2, 3}`? If it is the latter, why do you use a different approach in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use commas to separate the items in the array instead of adding the `char`s.

```
char[][] gameBoard = {
        {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
        {'-', '+', ' ', '+', '-'},
        {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
        {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '},
        {' ', '|', ' ', '|', ' '}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Addition of two chars in java like ('a' + 'b') will result 195 which is sum of ascii values for a(97) and b(98). In your case the results are (344, 208,344,208,344). You can lookup the value here: https://asecuritysite.com/coding/asc2